# It is possible to set server htdocs directory different from apache24 folder?

Tags: apache, web-services, htdocs

i am planning to set my htdocs folder on different Drive than the Apache 2.4 web service folder. It is possible to set server htdocs directory different from apache24 folder?

Example path :

This is my current root path : C:\Apache24\htdocs

Want to change to : E:\htdocs, but the Apache24 folder is remained at C:\ Drive. it is possible? please share the steps required to achieve this. thanks.

i had tried to change configuration file (httpd.conf) changed Server Root directory as per like this:

Define SRVROOT "E:/htdocs"

ServerRoot "${SRVROOT}"

but to no avail and cannot find the specified apache24 files as per this error:

c:\Apache24\bin>httpd -t
httpd: Syntax error on line 75 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_actions.so into server: The specified module could not be found.

please advise master. thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for the `DocumentRoot` directive that allows to change the root folder where a configured http host expects its resources in the local file system: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html#documentroot